# How do I add each individual character of a variable

Tags: python, encoding

I can work out how to add the two characters together, for example, 9+9 would return 8 rather than 18 (if that makes sense)
I need to make it work for 8 characters of two separate variables.
Here is the one character version:

```
def code_digit(n, key):
    result = n + key
    mod = result%10
    print (mod)

>>> code_digit(9,9)
8
```

Can you simplify the answer as much as possible, I am a beginner in python, thanks.

I understand there seems to be no goal, but it's for an assignment in my programming class.

It should return the sum of two numbers, wrapped round if it exceeds 9, so for example:

```
9+9 = (1)8
9+7 = (1)6
7+7 = (1)4
5+5 = (1)0
```

Ignore the brackets!

The final code should work like this...

```
>>> code_block(’12341234’,’12121212’)
’24462446’
>>> code_block(’66554433’,’44556677’)
’00000000’
```

Comment: “9+9 would return 8 rather than 18” – I don’t get it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I can't tell what the goal is, let alone what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal here. What is code_digit supposed to be doing? It seems like you want to pass a list rather than a variable since you want 9 numbers.

Comment: The code makes a bit more sense than the description("9+9 = 8 instead of 18" is due to the mod 10), but I'm still confused as to what the goal is.

Comment: It should return the sum of two numbers, wrapped round if it exceeds 9, so for example:

Comment: @chepner -- Wouldn't that return `9` then?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the desired output closely enough and had a different problem in mind.

Comment: @user2151912 The example is missing; could you add that to the question? And maybe more than just a single example (also multi-digit examples as you want them)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, we’re reusing your `code_digit` function, just a bit simplified and make it return the result instead of printing it, and also make it accept strings:

```
def code_digit(n, key):
    return (int(n) + int(key)) % 10

def code_block(num1, num2):
    n1, n2 = str(num1), str(num2)
    return ''.join(map(str, [code_digit(d1, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(n1, n2)]))
```

And it works!

```
>>> code_block(12341234, 12121212)
'24462446'
>>> code_block(66554433, 44556677)
'00000000'
```

But I’m not done yet. We can make this a bit more complex by allowing an arbitrary number of numbers:

```
def code_digits(*digits):
    return sum(map(int, digits)) % 10

def code_blocks(*blocks):
    return ''.join(map(str, (code_digits(*digits) for digits in zip(*map(str, blocks)))))

>>> code_blocks(123, 124, 457)
'694'
>>> code_blocks(1234, 5678, 9012, 3456)
'8260'
```

And want to support numbers with unequal lengths too (i.e. `6` and `15`, interpreted as `06` and `15`)? Sure.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def code_blocks(*blocks):
    return ''.join(reversed(list(map(str, (code_digits(*digits) for digits in zip_longest(*map(reversed, map(str, blocks)), fillvalue='0'))))))

>>> code_blocks(6, 15)
'11'
>>> code_blocks(123, 12, 235, 346, 45457)
'45053'
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point somethings might can become too pythonic, but if I understand what you doing this should work:

```
def code_digit(aStr, bStr):
    return ''.join([ str((int(x[0]) + int(x[1]))%10) for x in zip(aStr, bStr)])
```

Answer (score 0):

OK! Now I know what you're asking for!

```
def code_digit(n, key):
    remainder = (n+key)/10
    mod = (n+key)%10
    print "(%s)%s"%(remainder, mod)
```